# Connect K8055n Experiment Board to Ubuntu

Tags: compiling, udev

I purchased a K8055n Velleman Experimental Board and for some reason every program I run or if I try to access the board I get the following error:

```
Could not open the k8055 (port:0)
Please ensure that the device is correctly connected.
```

I do however suspect my rules are not correct but I did save
 velleman rules file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` but after reboot the OS freezes. I cannot work out what is wrong with my velleman rules.

I also tried to install the GUI but could not make the file.

```
~/k8055$ cd k8055gui
~/k8055/k8055gui$ cd src
~/k8055/k8055gui/src$ make g++ wx-config --cxxflags -c MyApp.cpp -o MyApp.o
/bin/sh: 1: wx-config: not found
In file included from MyApp.cpp:1:0: MyApp.h:4:19: fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [MyApp.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I have solved the issue with the GUI.
thanks to the following link:
http://www.panic1.be/category/programming/

Comment: Still battling with connecting the board...can someone please help....

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue on my board.....

In the C program there was a if statment that was not true and caused the board to fail.

In libk8055.c file the statment "if ((read_status == PACKET_LEN) && (CurrDev->data_in[1] == CurrDev->DevNo ))" was false....

static int ReadK8055Data(void)
{
    int read_status = 0, i = 0;

```
if (CurrDev->DevNo == 0) return K8055_ERROR;

for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
    read_status = usb_interrupt_read(CurrDev->device_handle, USB_INP_EP, (char *)CurrDev->data_in, PACKET_LEN, USB_TIMEOUT);
   if ((read_status == PACKET_LEN) && (CurrDev->data_in[1] == 11 )) //not sure why it must be 11
return 0;

    if (DEBUG)
        fprintf(stderr, "Read retry\n");
    }
return K8055_ERROR;
```

}